# Calculate $\int^{n+1}_1 \frac{(\{x\})^{[x]}}{[x]}dx$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$ and $\left\{ x\right\} =x-[x]$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

Let $n$ be a positive integer, for a real number $x$, let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding x and $\{x\} =x -[x]$ Then $$\int^{n+1}_1 \frac{(\{x\})^{[x]}}{[x]}dx$$ is equal to

(a) $\log_e(n)$

(b)  $\frac{1}{n+1}$

(c)  $\frac{n}{n+1}$

(d)  $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}$

Please suggest how to proceed in such cases not getting any clue how to proceed in cases of fractional part and greatest integral cases. please guide will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Split the integral into $n$ parts to get rid of all the $[\hphantom x]$ and $\{\hphantom x\}$.

Comment: KVPY huh ? Split the integral into $n$ parts and add them up. In some cases, you the integrand is periodic for example $\int_0^{10} x-[x] dx$ whereas at other times the integrals can easily be evaluated by looking at the area from the graph, which is easily found out.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{\left\{ x\right\} ^{\left[x\right]}}{\left[x\right]}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\left\{ x\right\} ^{\left[x\right]}}{\left[x\right]}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\int_{k}^{k+1}\left\{ x\right\} ^{k}dx=
 $$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\int_{k}^{k+1}\left(x-k\right)^{k}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}u^{k}du=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\left(k+1\right)}=
 $$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}.
 $$